# How to do convolution in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, convolution

I am trying to find convolution in OpenCV using filter2D method but the result is not correct

```
import cv2 as cv
import scipy.signal as sig
import numpy as np
b=np.asarray([[1,2,0,1,2],
              [2,3,1,1,2],
              [1,4,2,2,0],
              [3,2,3,3,0],
              [1,0,0,2,1]
              ],dtype=np.uint8)

w=np.asarray([[1,1,1],
              [1,1,2],
              [2,1,1]],dtype=np.uint8)
w_r=np.asarray([[1,1,1],
                [2,1,1],
                [1,1,1]
                ],dtype=np.uint8)
print(sig.convolve2d(b,w,mode="same"))
kernel_r=np.asarray([[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[2,1,1]])
print("-------")
print(cv.filter2D(b,-1,w_r))
```

First output is generated by scipy.signal.convolve2D that is correct. The second output is generated by OpenCV filter2D which is not correct. how can i get the correct results.

```
[[ 8 10 10  7  7]
 [15 18 20 14  9]
 [18 23 26 18 10]
 [15 21 22 16 11]
 [ 8 13 13  9  8]]
-------
[[23 16 15 11 13]
 [25 18 19 12 13]
 [28 22 25 16 16]
 [19 19 20 16 18]
 [15 18 18 15 19]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume, you wanted to use some rotated kernel `w_r` in your `cv.filter2d` call as also mentioned in the [`filter2d`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04) documentation:

> If you need a real convolution, flip the kernel using [**`flip`**](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaca7be533e3dac7feb70fc60635adf441) and [...]

So, first problem is, that your manually set `w_r` is not the correct, flipped version of `w`, you forgot a `2` there.

Second problem comes from, how [`scipy.sig.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) handles boundaries:

> **boundary : str {‘fill’, ‘wrap’, ‘symm’}, optional**
>
> A flag indicating how to handle boundaries:
>
> `fill`
>
> pad input arrays with fillvalue. (default)

From the obtained values after convolution, it seems that the boundary is padded with `0`. There's a similar option for OpenCV's `filter2d`, see the [`BorderTypes`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5), specifically `cv.BORDER_CONSTANT`. From tests it seems, that `0` is the default value here!? (Couldn't find any documentation on that by now.)

So, the corrected code could look like this (unnecessary stuff omitted here):

```py
import cv2 as cv
import scipy.signal as sig
import numpy as np

b=np.asarray([[1,2,0,1,2],
              [2,3,1,1,2],
              [1,4,2,2,0],
              [3,2,3,3,0],
              [1,0,0,2,1]
              ], dtype=np.uint8)

w=np.asarray([[1,1,1],
              [1,1,2],
              [2,1,1]], dtype=np.uint8)

print(sig.convolve2d(b, w, mode="same"))
print("-------")
print(cv.filter2D(b, -1, cv.flip(w, -1), borderType=cv.BORDER_CONSTANT))
```

Now, both outputs show the same result:

```
[[ 8 10 10  7  7]
 [15 18 20 14  9]
 [18 23 26 18 10]
 [15 21 22 16 11]
 [ 8 13 13  9  8]]
-------
[[ 8 10 10  7  7]
 [15 18 20 14  9]
 [18 23 26 18 10]
 [15 21 22 16 11]
 [ 8 13 13  9  8]]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for correcting my mistake. It took me many hours to dig out my problem. Any how thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

first_matrix=np.asarray([[1,2,0,1,2],
              [3,3,1,1,2],
              [1,4,2,2,0],
              [3,2,3,1,0],
              ], dtype=np.uint8)

second_matrix=np.asarray([[1,1,1],
              [1,1,2],
              [2,1,1]], dtype=np.uint8)

# Convolve the two matrices

con_mat = cv2.filter2D(first_matrix, -1, second_matrix)
print('con-sharp1=',con_mat)
```